# Is it possible to make a wear app that connects to my android app activity(maps)

Tags: android, maps, sony-smartwatch

I have a program that has one activity which the user can record his trip **by pressing a button** from one place to an other.I want somehow to make a wear app that connects with this activity so the user can press that button from the smartwatch and basically do whatever the android activity does.

Here is the code in case it's helpful

**Map.java**

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

   //VARIABLES

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    //CALL SERVICE
    Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");

    //gpsStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpsStatus);
    dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distancePreview);

    newActL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newAct);
    startActL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Act);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timePreview);

    newActB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.newActB);
    stopActB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stopActB);
    gearMap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gearmap);

    List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("Arrival");
    spinnerArray.add("Departure");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ardep);
    sItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    List<String> spinnerArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray2.add("Running");
    spinnerArray2.add("Walking");
    spinnerArray2.add("Cycling");
    spinnerArray2.add("Roller skating");
    spinnerArray2.add("Skateboarding");
    spinnerArray2.add("Kickbiking");
    spinnerArray2.add("Teleporting");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray2);

    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    actCombo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.actCombo);
    actCombo.setAdapter(adapter2);
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (currentHour < 12) {
        actCombo.setSelection(GetInfo.arract - 1);
        sItems.setSelection(0);
    } else {
        actCombo.setSelection(GetInfo.depact - 1);
        sItems.setSelection(1);
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            3000,
            1, this);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    line = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.BLUE);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    fullnameside = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.fullnameside);
    emailside = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailside);
    fullnameside.setText("" + GetInfo.fullname);
    emailside.setText("" + GetInfo.email);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);

    //Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), ""+ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void getLocation() {
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "e paides", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    try {
        line.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        GMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title(""));
        GMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16.0f));
        steps++;
        getloc = true;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "gyhg" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void StopTrip(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Stop and upload your trip?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    float finalDistance = (float) (distance / 1000.0);
                    if (finalDistance < 2) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Map.this, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                    TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    // newActL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // startActL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    enabledActivity = false;
                    //database post
                    try {
                        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String formattedDate = df.format(currentTime);

                        Date currentTime2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss");
                        dateActEnd = df2.format(currentTime2);

                        String act = actCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String act_id = "7";
                        switch (act) {
                            case "Running":
                                act_id = "1";
                                break;
                            case "Walking":
                                act_id = "2";
                                break;
                            case "Cycling":
                                act_id = "3";
                                break;
                            case "Roller skating":
                                act_id = "4";
                                break;
                            case "Skateboarding":
                                act_id = "5";
                                break;
                            case "Kickbiking":
                                act_id = "6";
                                break;
                            case "Teleporting":
                                act_id = "7";
                                break;
                        }

                        String direcor;
                        if (sItems.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Arrival"))
                            direcor = "arrival";
                        else
                            direcor = "departure";

                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                        // String.format("%.1f", finalDistance)
                        URL obj = new URL("https://gekon.technologypark.cz/api/v1/record/create?user=" + LoginInfo.UserID
                                + "&date=" + formattedDate + "&distance=" + String.format("%.1f", finalDistance) + "&direction=" + direcor
                                + "&activity=" + act_id + "&polyline=" + PolyUtil.encode(line.getPoints()) + "&start=" + dateActStart
                                + "&end=" + dateActEnd + "&source=mobileapp");

                        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("ApiSecret", LoginInfo.ApiSecret);
                        conn.connect();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String output;
                        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
                            sb.append(output);

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                        JSONObject curRecord = new JSONObject(jsonObj.getString("data"));

                        Trips.datet.add(currentTime);
                        Trips.datestr.add(formattedDate);
                        Trips.act.add(act_id);
                        Trips.tripType.add(sItems.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        Trips.dist.add(String.format("%.1f", finalDistance));
                        Trips.trip_ids.add(curRecord.getString("trip_id"));
                        Trips.calc(++Trips.points);

                        TripsCalendarInfo.datet.add(currentTime);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.act.add(act_id);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.act_str.add(act);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.tripType.add(sItems.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        TripsCalendarInfo.dist.add(String.format("%.1f", finalDistance));
                        TripsCalendarInfo.datestr.add(formattedDate);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.trip_ids.add(curRecord.getString("trip_id"));
                        TripsCalendarInfo.trip_source.add("mobileapp");
                        TripsCalendarInfo.polyline.add(PolyUtil.encode(line.getPoints()));
                        TripsCalendarInfo.CanItrip();

                        float km_up = Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1)) + finalDistance;
                        int trip_up = Integer.parseInt(TripsInfo.trips.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1)) + 1;
                        TripsInfo.trips.set(TripsInfo.userRank - 1, "" + trip_up);
                        TripsInfo.km.set(TripsInfo.userRank - 1, String.format("%.1f", km_up));
                        TripsInfo.rankSort();

                        getloc = false;

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Map.this, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error upload, please check your options at gear button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    float finalDistance = (float) (distance / 1000.0);
    if (finalDistance < 2) {
        builder.setMessage("Your trip is below 2km and it will not be counted.\nAre you sure you want to stop?");
    }
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}


public void StartAct(View v) {
    timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    newActB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    stopActB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //gearMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //headerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);          // to hide Navigation icon
    //toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    handler = new Handler();

    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss");
    dateActStart = df.format(currentTime);
    StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);

    startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    //enabledActivity = true;
}

public void ChangeAct(View v) {
    if (newActL.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        newActL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startActL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        newActL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startActL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;

        UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;

        Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);

        Minutes = Seconds / 60;

        Hours = Minutes / 60;

        Seconds = Seconds % 60;

        Minutes = Minutes % 60;

        MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 100);

        timer.setText("Time: " + String.format("%02d", Hours) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", Minutes) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", Seconds));

        handler.postDelayed(this, 950);
    }

};

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    GMap = map;
    GMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(49.8117806, 15.6970293), 6.0f));
    if (!getloc)
        getLocation();
}
```

[image: Map.java]

Answer (score 1):

Using the Maps SDK for Android, you can create a map-based wearable app

The following code sample enables ambient mode in the app and in the map:

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

private MapFragment mMapFragment;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);

    // Enable ambient support, so the map remains visible in a simplified,
    // low-color display when the user is no longer actively using the app
    // and the app is still visible on the watch face.
    setAmbientEnabled();

    // ... Perform other activity setup processes here too ...
}

/**
 * Starts ambient mode on the map.
 * The API swaps to a non-interactive and low-color rendering of the map
 * when the user is no longer actively using the app.
 */
@Override
public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
    super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
    mMapFragment.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
}

/**
 * Exits ambient mode on the map.
 * The API swaps to the normal rendering of the map when the user starts
 * actively using the app.
 */
@Override
public void onExitAmbient() {
    super.onExitAmbient();
    mMapFragment.onExitAmbient();
}
```

}